# A variant of the Schwartz–Zippel lemma

Tags: probability, combinatorics, polynomials

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a nonzero polynomial. Let $d_1$ be the maximum exponent of $x_1$ in $f$ and let $f_1$ be the coefficient of $x_1^{d_1}$ in $f.$ Let $d_2$ be the maximal exponent of $x_2$ in $f_1$ and so on for $d_3,\ldots,d_n.$

I would like to show that if $S_1, \ldots, S_n \subseteq \mathbb{F}$ are arbitrary subsets and $r_i \in S_i$ are chosen uniformly at random then $$ Pr[f(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = 0] \leq \frac{d_1}{|S_1|} + \cdots + \frac{d_n}{|S_n|}.$$

The claim is obviously true for $n = 1$ but for multivariate polynomials I don't see how to prove the claim since I don't see how to handle the fact that we disregard from $f$ all the terms containing $x_1^{k}$ for $k < d_1.$

Comment: what is $f_2$? maybe you could give a small example say on 3 variables. thanks

Comment: @IgorShinkar $f_2$ is actually $f_1$ - the coefficient of $x_1^{d_1}$ in $f.$

Comment: Does it mean that $x_2$ may have a very high degree (higher than $d_2$, with the restriction that this term cannot be multiplied by $x_1^{d_1}$?

Comment: @IgorShinkar As far as I understand this problem, yes. This  is taken from an exercise section of a book, so I don't have any additional info except for what is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should do it

We prove the claim by induction on $n.$ For $n = 1$ the statement reduces to the well known fact that a polynomial (of a single variable) of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots. Assume thus that the claim holds for all polynomials with less than $n$ variables and let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a nonzero polynomial with degree sequence $(d_1,\ldots,d_n).$ By definition of the degree sequence we may write $f$ as $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=0}^{d_1} x_1^i f_i(x_2,\ldots,x_n).$$

Observe that (again, by the definition of the degree sequence) $f_{d_1}$ is not identical to zero. Let $(r_2,\ldots,r_n) \in S_2 \times \cdots \times S_n$ be chosen uniformly at random. By the induction hypothesis $$Pr[f_{d_1}(r_2,\ldots,r_n) = 0] \leq \frac{d_2}{|S_2|} + \cdots + \frac{d_n}{|S_n|}.$$ Now if $f_{d_1}(r_2,...,r_n) \ne 0$ then $x_1$ has degree $d_1$ in $$f_1(x_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)$$ and hence $$Pr[f(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = 0 | f_{d_1}(r_2,...,r_n) \ne 0] \leq \frac{d_1}{|S_1|}.$$

Let us now denote by $E$ the event that $f(r_1,\ldots,r_n) = 0$ and by $F$ the event $f_{d_1}(r_2,\ldots,r_n) = 0.$ We obtain $$Pr[E] = Pr[E \cap F]+Pr[E \cap \overline{F}] = Pr[F] Pr[E|F]+Pr[\overline{F}]Pr[E|\overline{F}] \leq Pr[F]+Pr[E|\overline{F}] \leq \sum_{i=1}^n d_i/|S_i|.$$

Answer (score 0):

This "variant of the Schwartz-Zippel Lemma" is in fact Lemma 1 from [Jack Schwartz's original paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.duke.edu%2Fcourses%2Ffall09%2Fcps230%2Fhws%2Fjacm.pdf&ei=Fe5WVYipGoTJtQXe_oGgBg&usg=AFQjCNHuuoh_EgwVbxgo7XTDzihqDV6Mcw&sig2=ix1tUNOXWXmKhuVY0BpVhA&bvm=bv.93564037,d.b2w&cad=rja).

Note that although it looks nice to phrase the statement and/or the proof in probabilistic language, it is certainly not necessary to do so: Schwartz phrases it as a pure counting argument, which is (even) shorter than Jernej's (nice) solution above.  I mention this because the first time I saw this kind of proof of the Schwartz-Zippel Lemma, I think I took the probabilistic stuff a bit too seriously: it really is a way of phrasing the argument rather than a proof technique.

I hope the textbook gives some indication of the provenance of this "exercise"!