# Number of zeroes in $S^n$ of a multivariate polynomial.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Suppose $f\in\mathbb{F}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a nonzero polynomial and let $d_i$ be the degree of $f$ in the variable $x_i$. Furthermore assume $S\subseteq\mathbb{F}$ with $\vert S\vert\geq\max_id_i$. I want to show that the number of zeroes of $f$ in $S^n$ is at most
$$
\vert S\vert^n-\prod_{i=1}^n(\vert S\vert-d_i).
$$
I tried to use the Schwartz-Zippel lemma repeatedly, but I did not get the right expression.
I also read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476431/a-variant-of-the-schwartz-zippel-lemma) question (and its answers) and tried to transfer it to the case here, but this did not work either.

Comment: @EricTowers In the example in your comment, the displayed expression would be $3^n-1$, not $3-1$. The former is indeed an upper bound for the number of zeroes of $f$ in $S^n$.

Comment: @EricTowers I think you are confusing OP; you made that comment _after_ they edited their post, so they think you are critiquing the post in its current form, while your comment was referring to the original form.

Comment: That's weird, my screen right now shows your comment as 28 min old and the edit as 37 min old. Also, when I click the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4120136/timeline), your comments do not show up in the list of events, though mine and OP's do. It is possible OP is seeing what I am seeing.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I saw it the same way you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this by induction on $n$, in a somewhat similar way to the [proof of the Schwarz-Zippel lemma given in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma).

Equivalently, you need to prove there are at least $\prod_{i=1}^n (|S|-d_i)$ inputs for which $f$ is **non**zero. Consider $f$ as a polynomial in the variable $x_n$, whose coefficients are polynomials in $\mathbb F[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}]$, i.e,
$$
f(x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{d_n} P_k(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})\cdot(x_n)^k
$$
Consider the highest degree coefficient, $P_{d_n}(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$. By induction, there are at least $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(|S|-d_i)$ ways to choose $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ so that $P_{d_n}(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})\neq 0$. For each of these assignments (view $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ as fixed as $x_n$ as a variable), $f(x_n)$ is a single-variable polynomial of degree $d_n$, so there are at least $|S|-d_n$ values of $x_n$ for which $f(x_n)\neq 0$. This completes the proof.